# Вопрос по поиску на сайте

Tags: php, sql

В базе существуют товары с разными измерительными (х,*,x) обозначениями. Например:

1. Кабель 3*1,5
2. Кабель 3х1,5
3. Кабель 3x1,5 (английский Х)

Поиск организован через MATCH AGAINST + библиотека similar. В Базе около 200 тыс наименований. Как можно сделать, чтобы при запросе, например, `Кабель 3*1,5`, если такого нет, то показывается существующий `Кабель 3х1,5` и наоборот

Была идея массово изменить названия через регулярку и привести к одному варианту (Например, к виду nXn). В этом также есть минусы. Вторая идея - заменить все измерительные на пробелы. В этом также есть минусы.

Готовый код не прошу. Прошу совета и/или направления мыслей.

Comment: ну два поиска по бд сделай, и результаты слей в один результат

Comment: @Jean-Claude увеличится время выполнения, что не есть хорошо. Сделал иначе, как писал в посте - регуляркой все записи в базе привел к одному измерительному символу и в момент ajax поиска также меняю *,х на русский х. Изначально чет голова не додумалась менять на лету *,x при ajax запросе. Сейчас вроде все нормально